# Извлечь данные из нескольких таблиц в массиве

Tags: php

Пытаюсь извлечь данные из базы.
Суть: Получаем GET переменную (Имя персонажа), подключаемся к базе "characters" извлекаем из переменной его "char_id", подключаемся к таблице "items" и извлекаем все данные, касательно "item_id" и "loc_data" по  "owner_id"..  char_id - находится в таблице characters и имеет идентичное число, как и owner_id (но owner_id находится в таблице items)

```
public function getCharItem($name){
    $db = $this->Connect(self::$_conf['db']);
    $character = $db->select('characters',array('charId'),array('char_name'=>$name));
    $ownerId = '';
    $item_list = $db->query("SELECT item_id,loc_data FROM `items` WHERE `owner_id` = ТУТ НУЖНО ПОДСТАВИТЬ CHARID")->fetchAll();

    if($item_list !== false and count($item_list) > 0){
        foreach($item_list as $key=>$onl){
            $ownerId[$key] = array(
                'id'=>$onl['item_id'],
                'loc_data'=>$onl['loc_data']  );
        }
        if(is_array($ownerId)){
            echo $this->XMLRender(array('Characters','Stat','CharBlock'),$ownerId,true);
        }
    }else{
      echo 0;
    }
}
```

Мне нужно получить по ID чара все items_id и вывести в xml. Но вывод из массива не корректен. Прошу помощи

Comment: Что хоть за зверь используется у вас в качестве Query Builder-a? Похоже что какая то обертка над PDO...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одним запросом с применением PDO:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
select item_id as id, loc_data
    from `items`
    where `owner_id` = (
        select charId
            from `characters`
            where `char_name` = :char_name
    )
SQL;

$item_list = $db->prepare($sql);
$item_list->execute([
    ':char_name' => $name;
]);

$item_list = $item_list->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($item_list);
```

Для [medoo.in](http://medoo.in/)

```
$sql = <<<SQL
select item_id as id, loc_data
    from `items`
    where `owner_id` = (
        select charId
            from `characters`
            where `char_name` = :char_name
    )
SQL;
// обращаемся к PDO
$item_list = $db->pdo->prepare($sql);
$item_list->execute([
    ':char_name' => $name;
]);

$item_list = $item_list->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($item_list);
```

Comment: Можно это сделать на основе моего кода? Я использую библиотеку medoo, и не особо поняла как использовать ваш код(

Comment: @Елизавета [medoo.in](http://medoo.in/)? тогда можно использовать [medoo::$pdo](http://medoo.in/api/pdo) - замените `$db->prepare($sql);` на `$db->pdo->prepare($sql);` - добавил пример в ответ